# Socrata Full dataset replace API

Tags: socrata

I've been trying to follow the [API docs](https://dev.socrata.com/publishers/replace.html) for a full replace, by POSTing the payload to the dataset's endpoint (/resource/~ID~.json). I'm being returned the following object, which shows nothing actually happened.

```
{
  "By RowIdentifier" : 0,
  "Rows Updated" : 0,
  "Rows Deleted" : 0,
  "Rows Created" : 0,
  "Errors" : 0,
  "By SID" : 0
}
```

The endpoint i'm hitting is a working copy, and all other kinds of authenticated requests I've made to the endpoints work, but just can't get the dataset replace to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. That's odd, you should get a count of records that failed in the "Errors" key if they didn't succeed. Can you share an example payload, maybe even just a few rows? And the dataset you're trying to update.

Comment: Hi Chris. Totally forgot about this post that I made; just working on this in spare time. Basically, i narrowed it down a bit... Fiddler works perfect, so this is in my code. I'm using Poweshell so it's something with that implementation that isn't playing nice.